# Nativescript pass fetch response data to a level text

Tags: android, post, httpresponse, nativescript

In my nativescript app,I am trying to bulid a level from the response of my API through fetch module.But I don't know how to bind the context in obserable.How to bind the context when page loaded.Here is my code-

Response from my api-

```
[{"value":"12000$"}]
```

I want to get that **value** from response in **{{price}}** in my level text.

view file-

```
 <Page loaded="loaded">
    <GridLayout>
     <Label text="{{ price }}"  horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center" tap="model" />
        </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Fetch request-

```
fetch("http://10.0.2.2:8000/get_model", {
         method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },

       body: JSON.stringify({
                 brand: data,
    })  
 }).then(r => { return r.json(); }).then(function (data) {  
 console.log(data[0].value);

 //How to push the value in obserable?

 }, function (e) {
     console.log("Error occurred " + e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var observableModule = require("data/observable");

var viewModel = new observableModule.Observable();
viewModel.set("ip", "none"); // initial value

function onLoaded(args) {
   var page = args.object;
   page.bindingContext = viewModel;

   fetch("http://httpbin.org/ip", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then(function (res) { return res.json(); })
    .then(function (data) {  
        console.log(data.origin); // make sure you are getting the value 
        viewModel.set("ip", data.origin); // binding to "price"

    })
}
exports.onLoaded = onLoaded;
```

and in your page.xml use the loaded event

```
<Page loaded="onLoaded">
    <Label text="{{ ip }}"/>
</page>
```

In this case, httpbin.org is returning the data in format

```
{"origin" : "some-ip-address-here"}
```

Comment: Sorry,It's not working for me.I am using javascript.

Comment: Its the almost identicl - you have to remove the typings (e.g. <Page>, EventData, etc.) and replace let with var. Also use the JS way to import your Observable from "data/observable" and you are good to go http://uatdocs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#how-to-create-a-binding

Comment: I have re-written the example in JavaScript + used a real server that returns dummy infor to show how to bbind the result from the promise to your viewModel

Comment: You have tried a lot,Mr. Nick lliev.I am appreciating that.But I have failed to make you understand my main problem.I have already bind the context from that response to build a Listview.Now,I am trying to build a Level from that response.How Can I bind that.My fetch request is not in my Controller JS rather in a Viewmodel.I hope,you will understand