# Update a View Model from a JSON response in an Externally required module/plugin

Tags: nativescript

If I have code like the following (from [Nativescript pass fetch response data to a level text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234986/nativescript-pass-fetch-response-data-to-a-level-text))

```
    var observableModule = require("data/observable");

    var viewModel = new observableModule.Observable();
    viewModel.set("ip", "none"); // initial value

    function onLoaded(args) {
       var page = args.object;
       page.bindingContext = vm;

       fetch("http://httpbin.org/ip", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        })
        .then(function (res) { return res.json(); })
        .then(function (data) {  
            console.log(data.origin); // make sure you are getting the value 
            viewModel.set("ip", data.origin); // binding to "price"

        })
    }
    exports.onLoaded = onLoaded;
```

If I want to make the fetch portion reusable and call it in an external file using the require method. How would I go about passing the json response from this piece of code:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
//this is fetch.js
   var response = '';
   exports.fetch = function() {
   fetch("http://httpbin.org/ip", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then(function (res) { return res.json(); })
    .then(function (data) {  
        console.log(data.origin); // make sure you are getting the value
        response = data;
    })};
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

Back To Here?

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var fetchIt = require("./fetch.js");
var viewModel = new observableModule.Observable();
viewModel.set("ip", "none"); // initial value

function onLoaded(args) {
   var page = args.object;
   page.bindingContext = vm;
   var data = fetchIt.fetch;
   viewModel.set("ip", data);
}
exports.onLoaded = onLoaded;
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

I know that this code isn't going to run so use it only as an example for what I am wanting to accomplish.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return the fetch promise, you can do a .then on it to assign the variable in your other js file. I try to stick with typescript, but I believe the following changes should help you on your way.

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
//this is fetch.js

   exports.fetch = function() {
   return fetch("http://httpbin.org/ip", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
    })
    .then(function (res) { return res.json(); })
    .then(function (data) {  
        console.log(data.origin); // make sure you are getting the value
        return data;
    })};
<!-- language: lang-js -->

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
var observableModule = require("data/observable");
var fetchIt = require("./fetch.js");
var viewModel = new observableModule.Observable();
viewModel.set("ip", "none"); // initial value

function onLoaded(args) {
   var page = args.object;
   page.bindingContext = vm;
   var data = fetchIt.fetch.then(function (data) {
       viewModel.set("ip", data);
    }
}
exports.onLoaded = onLoaded;
<!-- language: lang-js -->
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much. I am just getting into this stuff for my senior project and your help has been invaluable. I would love to pick your brain more on other problems if you would follow me. Thanks!